# IIS dumping ASPX files as plain text

Tags: iis, asp.net

After migrating to a new server many of our application files seem to be displaying as text/plain instead of executing, though sometimes they will seem to "partially" execute if we refresh the page.

So far, we have followed the steps described in [Microsoft KB#325093 regarding unexpected behavior from IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325093), but the issue has not been solved.  We have also ensured that the directories themselves have permission to execute scripts and executables, and that ASPX files are being interpreted by `aspnet_isapi.dll`.

Any ideas what else could be going wrong?

Comment: I guess also, the version of IIS might help in that the steps or solutions can be different between iis7,iis6,ii5 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that the ASP.Net Vx.x...etc extensions are "allowed" in the Web Service Extension configuration of IIS Manager?

While you're checking that, make sure that the aspnet_isapi.dll is listed in the "Required Files" tab of the properties of the extension (for version 2 at least anyway)...

Answer (score 0):

If this is Windows Server 2008, check in "Roles" / "Web Server IIS" in Server Manager if all necessary modules are installed: ASP.NET etc.

The default Windows Server installation doesn't include ASP.NET.